# SQL Query Table, column_name, Schema name, how many times that Column name was used, small sample (say the middle 10) of each of the column's data

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic

I want the Table_name, column_name, Schema_name and how many times that column name  was used and a  small sample (say the middle  or event top 10) of each of the column's data where the column result  is not null in a comma delimited format.

The columns will look like this:

```
Table_name , column_name, Schema_name, CountOfHowManyTimesThatColumnAppearsInAllSchemas, SampleDataFromTheTable
```

I have everything but the last part (the hardest by far). I will continue to work on it.

```
SELECT   
    Table_Catalog,
    TABLE_SCHEMA, 
    Table_name AS 'TableNameWhereColumnAppears',
    Column_name, 
    DATA_TYPE,
    Character_Maximum_length,
    is_nullable,
    COUNT(Column_name) OVER (PARTITION  By Column_name) AS 'CountOfHowManyTimesThatColumnAppearsInAllSchemas'
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
ORDER BY 
    COLUMN_NAME, 'CountOfHowManyTimesThatColumnAppearsInAllSchemas'
```

I have tried some Dynamic SQL but I just can not get it going.

Sample result:

```
Table_name,column_name,Schema_name,CountOfHowManyTimesThatColumnAppearsInAllSchemasOFDatabase,SampleDataFromThe schema.Table 
Apple         Abbrev        Tre                20                                         Wolfram,GREEN_Apple,Sour,Cooking
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then try something like this

```
SELECT
    Table_Catalog,
    TABLE_SCHEMA,
    Table_name AS 'TableNameWhereColumnAppears',
    Column_name,
    DATA_TYPE,
    Character_Maximum_length,
    is_nullable,
    (
        select
            count(*)
        from
            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c1
        where
            c1.Table_Catalog = c.Table_Catalog
            and c1.Column_name = c.Column_name
    ) as 'CountOfHowManyTimesThatColumnAppearsInAllSchemas',
    CONCAT(
        'SELECT TOP 10 STRING_AGG(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), ',
        Column_name,
        '), '','') FROM ',
        TABLE_SCHEMA,
        '.',
        Table_name,
        ' where ',
        Column_name,
        ' is not NULL;'
    ) as sample_query
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
where
    Column_name = 'id'
ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME, CountOfHowManyTimesThatColumnAppearsInAllSchemas;
```

Remove `c1.Table_Catalog = c.Table_Catalog` if you want to count that Column_name among all databases.
You'll have the queries for getting sample data, but it is up to you to wrap that into dynamic SQL and assemble the result.

Comment: my bad. they never write it in question itself, and i didn't notice the tag. but no big deal, just change GROUP_CONCAT to STRING_AGG and LIMIT to TOP and that should do it.

Comment: Thank you Roasty Chips,  your comment about the Where Clause was Great.   I got the answer and Pulled it into T-SQL.  It was better than the answer I wanted.  I don't post often so I will have to figure this thing out